# Using curl to send emails through Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl

Using [this](https://coderwall.com/p/3vqf2g/send-emails-via-amazon-ses-with-bash-and-curl) link i tried to send emails to Amazon SES. But could not.
The error being:

```
    <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">   <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
        <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: noreply@myorg.com</Message>   </Error>
<RequestId>4242cec6-5002-11e6-95bf-b7dbdddce018</RequestId> </ErrorResponse>
```

**This seeming obvious**, I contacted devops, but alas!! They said the email is indeed verified.
The I tried:

- With different endpoint
- With different email(That was verified)

But the same error repeats.

Amazon says use [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html), but i do not have the smtp user creds. 
Plus the question remains why the curl does not work. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

For better readability adding curl :

> curl -v -X POST -H "Date: $(date -R)" -H "X-Amzn-Authorization:
>   AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=ORG_ACCESS_KEY, Algorithm=HmacSHA256,
>   Signature=$(echo -n $(date -R) | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac
>   ORG_SECRET_KEY -binary | base64 -w 0)" --data-urlencode
>   "Message.Body.Text.Data=Test Message" --data-urlencode
>   "Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=my_email" --data-urlencode
>   "Source=myorg_verified_email_id" --data-urlencode "Action=SendEmail"
>   --data-urlencode "Message.Subject.Data=Test AWS Message" "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"

Comment: Have you lifted Sandbox limits off your SES account? Maybe you need to verify receiver too? Have you tried verifying sender URL? Why you don't have SES credentials? Why can't generate new ones?

Comment: I do not have access to the creds because they are prod for the org and common across teams. I asked about the Sandbox limits from Devops and they said no issues with this. The sender url and the box runs the java code i have. Just the curl does not run.  I can't generate because its prod for a big org. :)

Comment: I've not done it in SES but I can help you with SparkPost if you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the smtp creds are the only way to get through this problem.
API Key and passwords only work using the amazon sdk. This [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html)
shows the different methods for authentication using SES.